# Jasperstarter could not run reports with charts

Tags: highcharts, jasper-reports, jasperstarter

I created doughnut chart in my jrxml file and tried to export it using jasperstarter with the below command in Command Prompt:

**jasperstarter pr rpt.jasper -t postgres -u postgres -f pdf -H myhost -n myDB -o rpt -p myPassword -P myPar1=5**

But I am getting the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from InputStream.
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedObjectPersistenceService.load(SerializedObjectPersistenceService.java:60)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedReportPersistenceService.load(SerializedReportPersistenceService.java:40)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getResource(DefaultRepositoryService.java:149)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:144)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:112)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.loadReport(JRFillSubreport.java:398)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:365)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:427)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:341)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:500)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2022)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:748)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:582)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:90)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
at de.cenote.jasperstarter.Report.fill(Report.java:253)
at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.processReport(App.java:217)
at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.main(App.java:102)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from InputStream.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:290)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:262)
at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedObjectPersistenceService.load(SerializedObjectPersistenceService.java:56)
... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.StandardChartComponent
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:89)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.readObject(JRBaseReport.java:777)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:278)
... 24 more
```

The same command works if I remove the chart element from the report.
Could anyone tell me what should be the solution to this issue?

Comment: Highcharts are from Pro edition of Jaspersoft products. Looks like you trying to use higharts using community edition

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the reply. So do you mean to say that Jasperstarter cannot run Highcharts? In that case, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Cross-posted on Jasperstarter issue tracker: https://cenote-issues.atlassian.net/browse/JAS-106